# How to do a partial sum of table rows in LiveCycle - Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, livecycle

I have 4 rows (and 3 columns) in a table. The last row is the total. I need to sum only the first two rows, excluding the last one. The problem is they are all calculated values from different tables, how do I do it? I am new to Adobe LiveCycle and Javascript.

This is what I currently have:

```
var times = xfa.resolveNodes("Row2[*].Time");
this.rawValue = Calculate.SumRawValues(times);
```

I am trying something like this:

```
var times = xfa.resolveNodes("Row2[*].Time");
var timesFlushing = xfa.resolveNode("Row2[2].Time");
this.rawValue = Calculate.SumRawValues(times) - timesFlushing.value;
```

or something like this:

```
var times = xfa.resolveNodes("Row2[*].Time");
this.rawValue = Calculate.SumRawValues(times) - xfa.resolveNode("Row2[2].Time");
```

or even this:

```
this.rawValue = Row2.Time + xfa.resolveNode("Row2[1].Time")
```

Clearly I am new to this and none of these work. Help please??? Comments?

Answer (score 0):

For each total cell, in its calculate event, add something like this:

```
this.rawValue = Row1.DecimalField1.rawValue + Row2.DecimalField2.rawValue + Row3.DecimalField3.rawValue;
```

[Here](http://www.filedropper.com/stackoverflow) is my example form, but plz note, it'll work (this method) only with a permanent amount of rows/cells.